# How to send SIGKILLs to entire pipeline?

Tags: bash, pipe, kill, timeout

```
while true; do 
    # process substitution instead of usual pipeline to avoid waiting for all programs
    handle_input_with_timeout < <( prog1 | prog2 | prog3 )
    echo "Data stopped flowing. Trying again"
    # perminate stuck programs in previous pipeline, then try again
    sleep 5
done
```

How to reliably get rid of prog1, prog2 and prog3 that can get stuck and hold resources necessary to try again?

Can it be done in Bash alone or I need to use cgroups?

Comment: See [Best way to kill all child processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/392022)

Comment: @terdon, Sending SIGKILL to the process group that runs pipeline also kills bash running this script. All these programs appear in one process group. How to easily move them to separate process group?

Comment: Found one solution...

Comment: I was thinking you could target the while loop's group. Not the parent shell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with process groups (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/392155/266720)) and `setsid` to start new one:

```
while true; do 

    handle_input_with_timeout < <( setsid bash -c '
          printf -- "-$$" > /tmp/saved_process_group.pid
          prog1 | prog2 | prog3
          ')
    echo "Data stopped flowing. Trying again"
    kill -9 $(< /tmp/saved_process_group.pid )

    sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `timeout` include in `GNU's coreutils`:

```
timeout <time in second> bash -c "prog1 | prog2 | prog3"
```

Example:

```
timeout 5 bash -c "pwd | sleep 10"
```

Use `time` to make sure it works:

```
$ time timeout 5 bash -c "pwd | sleep 10"

real    0m5.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Comment: The timeout should be extended each time something appears on stdin. It should work like watchdog: data is flowing => OK, data interrupted => restart the chain.

Comment: @Vi.: How do you know data is OK or interrupted?

Comment: `handle_input_with_timeout` sets up `alarm(2)` and rewinds it each time new data appears on stdin. If SIGALRM comes, it prints "timeout" and exits.

Comment: Why don't you use `timeout` instead of `alarm()` in your `handle_input_with_timeout` function?

Comment: What `timeout`? A program (`timeout(1)`)? It's not for this use case. Or you mean starting `timeout(1)` to each line of input data? `alarm(2)` and SIGALRM is easy to set up in Perl...

Comment: @Vi.: Yes, starting timeout(1) to each line of input data. AFAIK, `timeout` in bash is equivalent to use `perl` with `SIGALRM`.

Comment: There are typically multiple lines per second (one video frame == one line), so starting a program for each line is inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

One technique to control an errant pipeline is to count the number of pipeline processes after a while.  If they haven't finished, then zap them and restart.

In this example code we use ask [Bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) for its process id (the `$$` variable), then use [pgrep](http://man.cx/?page=pgrep&do%5Bgo%5D=go) to find all sub-processes of the script.  That is, `pgrep` tells us all the workflow process IDs.  If there are any, then we use the corresponding [pkill](http://man.cx/?page=pgrep&do%5Bgo%5D=go) command to squash them before a restart.

In addition, we use the [date](http://man.cx/?page=date&do%5Bgo%5D=go) command to output a pretty log file, showing what the system is doing at what time.

**source**: https://github.com/shavenwarthog/johntellsall/tree/master/karma/kill-pipeline

---

```
#!/bin/bash

# pipeline.sh -- start workflow; restart if jammed

while true; do

    date '+%X workflow starting'
    (sleep 30; echo gin) &
    (sleep 30; echo tonic) &

    date '+%X waiting for workflow to complete'
    sleep 5

    # count number of child procs (ie: workflow procs)
    # If there are any, kill them then restart.
    if pgrep -cP $$ > /dev/null ; then 
        date '+%X workflow jammed -- restarting; trying again'
        pkill -P $$
        sleep 2
        continue
    fi

    date '+%X workflow done!'
    break

done
```

---

**Test run**:

start workflow control script

`$ ./pipeline.sh &`

`[1] 21291`

`02:06:39 PM workflow starting`

`02:06:39 PM waiting for workflow to complete`

The pipeline scripts waits for a few seconds, but the workflow procs are still running, as they start with a "sleep 30"

Pipeline detects workflow is jammed, complains and kills them before a restart.

`02:06:44 PM workflow jammed -- restarting; trying again`

`./pipeline.sh: line 27: 21293 Terminated              ( sleep 30; echo gin )`

`./pipeline.sh: line 27: 21294 Terminated              ( sleep 30; echo tonic )`

`02:06:46 PM workflow starting`

`02:06:46 PM waiting for workflow to complete`

Pipeline is now waiting for workflow to complete.  Here we'll cheat and manually make the pipeline complete by killing the workers.

`$ pkill -f sleep`

`./pipeline.sh: line 27: 21363 Terminated              sleep 30`

`./pipeline.sh: line 27: 21365 Terminated              sleep 5`

`./pipeline.sh: line 27: 21364 Terminated              sleep 30`

`tonic`

Pipeline script now notices all workers are done, thus the pipeline is done.  It make a concluding log message, then exits.

`02:07:16 PM workflow done!`

`[1]+  Done                    ./pipeline.sh`